# Subgroups of Functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

$\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all real-valued functions of a real variable.

I'm trying to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

1. $G = \langle \mathcal{F}, + \rangle, H = \{ f \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}): f \text{ is a periodic of period } \pi \}$. A function $f$ is said to be periodic of period $a$ if there is a number $a$, called the period of $f$, such that $f(x) = f(x + na)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

(i). Let $f, g \in H$, then $f(x) = f(x + n\pi)$ and $g(x) = g(x + n\pi)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. The sum $[f + g](x) = f(x) + g(x) = f(x + n\pi) + g(x + n\pi) = [f + g](x + n\pi)$. Thus $f + g \in H$.

(ii). Let $f \in H$, then $f(x) = f(x + n\pi)$. The inverse $[-f](x) = -[f(x)] = -f(x + n\pi) = [-f](x + n\pi) \in H$. Thus the inverse $-f \in H$.

So $H$ must be a subgroup of $G$.

Is my proof correct?

---

Update: How would I go about showing H is not empty? Why is that important? And can I make the assumption that H is not empty?

Comment: I would say that in part (ii) you need to change $a$ fo $\pi$, and you are missing the final step of going from $-f(x+na)$ to $[-f](x+na)$, thus showing $[-f]$ is periodic of period $\pi$. Also, you forgot to verify that $H$ is not empty.

Comment: Nearly. In (ii) you’ve left off a step: $-f(x+na)=[-f](x+na)$ is needed to finish showing that $-f$ is periodic, and $a$ should be $\pi$. Also, (i) and (ii) could be vacuously true, so you need to check that $H\ne\varnothing$. By the way, it’s sufficient to show that $f-g \in H$ whenever $f,g \in H$; that’s equivalent to the conjunction of your (i) and (ii).

Comment: @Gary: In (i) he simply has to show that for any fixed $n$, $[f+g](x+n\pi)=[f+g](x)$, so it *is* the same $n$. ‘Inverse’ here refers to the inverse in the group $G$; this is an additive group, and the inverse is simply the negative of the original function, which certainly is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @gary: You are misreading the problem. The elements of $H$ are the functions with period $\pi$. The definition says that $h$ has period $a$ if for every natural number $n$, $f(x+na) = f(x)$. The period of both functions is assumed to be the same, $\pi$. So you don't have the situation where $f$ and $g$ have different periods. The $n$ is not the period, $\pi$ is the period.

Comment: The constant function has period n for any n , i.e., if f(x)=C, then f(x+y)=C for any y.

Comment: @Arturo: How would I go about showing H is not empty? Why is that important? And can I make the assumption that H is not empty?

Comment: @gary: Your last comment is irrelevant. If $f$ and $g$ are in $H$, then $f(x) = f(x+n\pi)$ for all integers $n$, and $g(x)=g(x+n\pi)$ for all integers $n$. In order to show that $f+g$ is in $H$, you don't need to show that $\pi$ is the smallest period, you just need to show that $f+g$ is periodic with period $\pi$; that is, you need to show that for any (particular) integer $n$, $(f+g)(x+n\pi) = (f+g)(x)$.

Comment: I see; I was using my own def. that there existed _some_  n with $f(x+n\pi)=f(x)$. I will try your fancy tricks next time, and I will actually read the question carefully.

Comment: @Jon: It's important to show that $H$ is not empty because the empty set is not a subgroup, but it certainly satisfies the two conditions you checked (by vacuity). The easiest way to show that $H$ is not empty is by explicitly exhibiting a function that is in $H$. No, you cannot simply assume that $H$ is not empty. For instance, $K=\{g\in\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})\mid g^2(x)\lt 0\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a subset of $G$ that satisfies that if $f,g\in K$ then $f+g\in K$, and if $f\in K$ then $-f\in K$, but it's not a subgroup because it is empty.

Comment: @gary: "there exists some $n$ with $f(x+n\pi) = f(x)$" only shows that $f$ has period an integer multiple of $\pi$ (and that, only if you exclude $n=0$). It's not the definition of "has period $\pi$".

Comment: @Arturo: yes, it's a bad habit of mine to solve problems imposing my own definitions . I thought this was an informal use of periodic. Let me erase all my comments in this question and I will be more careful and will actually read the question.

Comment: @Arturo: When you say, "explicitly exhibiting a function that is in $H$," do mean just giving an example of a function that is in $H$? And is $K$ empty because there is no real-valued function squared that is less than 0?

Comment: @Jon: Yes, that is exactly what I  mean: just say "$H$ is not empty, because the function `give explicit example` is in $H$". That proves $H$ is not empty. Yes, $K$ is empty because no real valued function can satisfy the given condition. But that means that the implication $(f,g\in K)\Rightarrow (f+g\in K)$ is true (because the antecedent is always false), and likewise $(f\in K)\Rightarrow (-f\in K)$ is true (because the antecedent is always false). If you read the definition of "subgroup" carefully, as well as the associated theorems, you will see non-emptiness is always there.

Comment: Jon:Wow, let me see if I can redeem the mess I made: think of familiar functions defined on the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of (ii), just before the word "Thus", you wrote $\in H$.  You should delete that.  In the first place $-f(x+na)$ is one *value* if $-f$, whereas it's the function $-f$, not one of its values, that you want to show is in $H$.  Also, before the word "Thus", each equality and each binary relation should be something that you *already know* is true, whereas $\text{something}\in H$ is what you're trying to prove, not something already known.

Other than that the proof is correct.

I don't like writing "where" when you mean "for every".  The fact is that some somewhat sloppy writers put a trailing "where $m\in\mathcal{Q}$" or something like that when they mean "**for every** $m\in\mathcal{Q}$", and some write "where $m\in\mathcal{Q}$" when they mean "**for some** $m\in\mathcal{Q}$", and then the reader is supposed to figure out which, if either, is meant.  Putting "where...." after any sort of mathematical equality or relation or the like should be done when you're trying to explain what your notation or your terms mean, not when you're trying to say "for every" or "for some".

Comment: Your second paragraph isn’t quite right: Arturo and I pointed out a couple more small flaws that you missed.